# Changing color code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function color(){
 var color = "#"
 for(var i = 0; i<6; i++){
  color += Math.floor((Math.random()*16)).toString(16);
 };
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function change(){
 setInterval(color(), 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button id='button' onmouseover="change();" style='width:50px; height:50px; margin-left:auto;'>click</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src='js.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to make the auto changing background coding.

I want to change the background color every 1 second.
but it just change color once when i put my mouse on.

what is the problem?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question (@adeneo already handled that) but instead of generating 6 separate hex codes, consider doing `Math.floor(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF).toString(16)` - it'll be a bit more performant and also theoretically have better entropy on most `Math.random` implementations. Plus, it's less code. :) https://jsfiddle.net/uLurgvzk/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling the function, not referencing it in the `setInterval` call.

Change it to

```
setInterval(color, 1000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/uLurgvzk/)

When you add the parentheses to a function, it's called, and the returned result, which is always `undefined` unless something else is defined in the called function, will be returned.

What you're doing is the same as

```
var fn = color(); // returns undefined

setInterval(fn, 1000); // undefined, 1000
```

Comment: Added a bit more explanation to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working snippet. 
What I changed was

1. `onmousehover` was replaced with `oneclick()` (since it says click on the button)
2. In the `setInterval` function call, `color` doesn't need the brackets

```js
function color(){
 var color = "#"
 for(var i = 0; i<6; i++){
  color += Math.floor((Math.random()*16)).toString(16);
 };
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function change(){
 setInterval(color, 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button id='button' onclick="change();" style='width:50px; height:50px; margin-left:auto;'>click</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src='js.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

```html
<body>
  <button id='button' onmouseover="change()" style='width:50px; height:50px; margin-left:auto;'>click</button>
</body>

<script>
  function color() {
    var color = "#"
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += Math.floor((Math.random() * 16)).toString(16);
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

  function change() {
    setInterval(color(), 1000);
  }
</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9cxw9jL0/

Comment: How does this fix the problem? It's still calling `color` instead of passing it into `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

I have changes some code and you can find in plunker.

```
<https://plnkr.co/edit/sKpJQqRohICD63AQjgTx?p=preview>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for your problem

```js
function colorchanger(){
    setInterval(function(){
              
                 var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];

        }
       document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
               



    },300);

   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 



</head>
<body>
<button onclick="colorchanger();" >Change Color</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and makes a bunch of other unrelated changes, while also making the code much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I call only one function. is this code complicated your.this code is easier than yours i think so

Comment: The edits fix the problem. My other criticisms stand.